# render_to_response with HTTP response headers

Tags: django, http-headers, render-to-response

How to use HTTP response headers with Django render_to_response

I want to use Cache-Control but can't tell if it is working.  Is the following correct:

```
render_to_response(templatename, {'Cache-Control':'no-cache'},context_instance=RequestContext(httpreq))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set headers directly on the response object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-headers

```
response = render_to_response(...)
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
return response
```